# How to deal with the fact that dynamically loaded DLL can be unloaded by Windows even if reference count is not zero?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

The documentation says *"The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count)."*

This causes a significant problem and it's unclear how to solve it. Now about the problem. Suppose we have an executable *E* that explicitly depends on a DLL library *L1* that dynamically loads a DLL library *L2* via LoadLibrary.
When *E* finishes and the process starts terminating *L2* can be unloaded before *L1*. This can be problematic if *L1* has an object with static storage duration which contains some of the resources obtained from from *L2* because those resources will start destroying at *L1* unloading time which means a call to already unloaded *L2* will result in a crash.

One of the possible solutions (of even the only one) is not to destroy the object with static storage duration. The drawback of this solution is that *L1* can potentially be loaded/unloaded dynamically multiple times, which increases the memory leak. This can be mitigated by using DllMain where we could check whether the process terminates or the library is unloaded via FreeLibrary.

So far everything seems to work just fine. But there is more. Suppose we want *L1* to be a static library that links with a DLL library named *L_SHIM*. So now the executable *E* is linked with the *L_SHIM* and the whole DllMain trick doesn't work anymore. Actually, nothing seems to work if we are not allowed to modify *L_SHIM* library.

Has anybody had to solve a problem like this? I'd appreciate any thoughts about possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When handling `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, a DLL should free resources such
> as heap memory only if the DLL is being unloaded dynamically (the
> **`lpReserved`** parameter is **NULL**). If the process is terminating (the **`lpvReserved`** parameter is **non-NULL**), all threads in the
> process except the current thread either have exited already or have
> been explicitly terminated by a call to the `ExitProcess` function,
> which might leave some process resources such as heaps in an
> inconsistent state. In this case, it is not safe for the DLL to clean
> up the resources. Instead, the DLL should allow the operating system
> to reclaim the memory.

so you need check `lpvReserved` inside `DllMain`:

let you have global variable:

```
bool g_is_terminating = false;
```

and in `DllMain`

```
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: g_is_terminating = (reserved != nullptr);
```

destructors of objects with global/static called after `DllMain`. so you can check in destructor `g_is_terminating`;

```
if (!g_is_terminating) { do_something(); }
```

---

another and always useful and very simply way, use *undocumented* api

```
//This routine returns the status of process shutdown.

EXTERN_C
DECLSPEC_IMPORT
BOOLEAN
NTAPI
RtlDllShutdownInProgress();
```

this api exported from *ntdll.dll* - so you need use or *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib* (in case you not use crt)

simply call `RtlDllShutdownInProgress();` from destructror and if return true - not access another dll - this mean process is terminating

```
if (!RtlDllShutdownInProgress()) { do_something(); }
```

internally, in ntdll exist global variable

```
BOOLEAN LdrpShutdownInProgress = FALSE;
```

and when `ExitProcess` called - than `LdrShutdownProcess` called from `ntdll.dll` and at begin it set `LdrpShutdownInProgress = TRUE;`
the `RtlDllShutdownInProgress()` simply return value of `LdrShutdownProcess`

---

and about
"The system unloads a module when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count)."

this is false. system not unload any dll after process begin terminates. even if direct call `FreeLibrary/LdrUnloadDll` at this time (after *LdrpShutdownInProgress* set to `TRUE`) - dll will be not unloaded. really - no big sense do this - because soon all process will be destroyed.

*..which means a call to already unloaded *L2* will result in a crash.*
really L2 never will eb unloaded after call `ExitProcess`. **but** `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` will be called inside *L2*. and this will be always *before* *L1* `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` notification (this notify send in LIFO order. so if *L1* load *L2* - `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` called in *L1* before in *L2* - *L1* before *L2* in `InInitializationOrderLinks` list. and on process exit - this list (`InInitializationOrderLinks`) processed in reverse order .

so *L2* , despite still in memory, will be already in "uninit" state (after `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` ) call some api inside *L2* can lead to undefined results. it may work without any problem, or crash or random result. this even more worse, compare stable crash

Comment: OP has already stated he can't use any solution relying on `DllMain`().

Comment: @user207421 - sorry, i not note at begin *L1 to be a static library that links with a DLL* - add another solution with `RtlDllShutdownInProgress()` call. it even more simply, but undocumented api (however because it very simply - never will be changed or removed)

Comment: @RbMm, according to the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050523-05/?p=35573) the dynamically loaded DLL is not added to the dependency list hence it can be unloaded independently from the other dependencies.

Comment: @Nobody - i have not less knowledge in this topic compare to blog author. and what you try say ?

Comment: @Nobody what you try say ?

Comment: I'm not here to question your expertise. I do understand what you suggested, the solution with `RtlDllShutdownInProgress` seems to be working fine, thanks for the suggestion. I was just curious why you say that L2 will always be detached before L1 due to LIFO notification order while the blog says that the order is not guaranteed. The blog thing aside, if the L2 is always detached first then it means L1 can never contain any resource from L2, is this correct?

Comment: @Nobody - until you not call `FreeLibrary(L2)` it will be not unloaded. about *LIFO notification order* on process termination (not unload but `DLL_PROCESS_DATACH` call) - related to `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY::InInitializationOrderLinks`. another question - in which order dlls will be inserted in this list. in case you direct call `LoadLibrary` - your dll already in list and new loaded dll will be after your in list. this is fact. also this article is too old. was big changes how loader build graph and call dll entry points after this

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed explanation.